# Permission denied for Git Clone when I do npm install

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, github, ubuntu-14.04

I have git dependencies in my package.json file. 
When I do **sudo npm install** in my react app folder, I get this error

```
    npm ERR! code 1
    npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master 
    https://github.com/lrojas94/react-file-base64.git /home/admin1/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-462782fb
    npm ERR! /home/admin1/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-462782fb/.git: Permission denied
    npm ERR! 

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/admin1/.npm/_logs/2017-07-18T08_58_10_906Z-debug.log
    admin1@ubuntu:~/hys_pms/ui$ nohup: appending output to ‘nohup.out’
```

This is my package.json

```
    {
      "name": "react-hys-app",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "annogenerate": "^0.8.1",
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "cors-prefetch-middleware": "^1.0.0",
        "es6-promise": "^4.1.0",
        "express": "^4.15.3",
        "fixed-data-table": "^0.6.4",
        "flexbox-react": "^4.4.0",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "images-upload-middleware": "^1.1.1",
        "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
        "jquery": "^3.2.1",
        "react": "^15.3.1",
        "react-autosuggest": "^9.0.1",
        "react-avatar-cropper": "^0.1.3",
        "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.8",
        "react-bootstrap-autosuggest": "^0.5.0",
        "react-bootstrap-date-picker": "^5.0.1",
        "react-bootstrap-table": "^3.3.1",
        "react-checkbox-list": "0.0.2",
        "react-datepicker": "^0.51.0",
        "react-datetime": "^2.8.10",
        "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
        "react-dual-listbox": "^1.1.0",
        "react-edit": "^6.3.0",
        "react-file-base64": "git+https://github.com/lrojas94/react-file-base64.git",
        "react-flexbox-grid": "^1.1.3",
        "react-grid-layout": "^0.14.6",
        "react-images-uploader": "^1.0.1",
        "react-pagify": "^2.2.0",
        "react-panelgroup": "^1.0.2",
        "react-radio-button-group": "^1.2.5",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
        "react-router": "^2.7.0",
        "react-s-alert": "^1.3.0",
        "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
        "react-visibility-toggles": "^1.1.1",
        "reactabular-resizable": "^8.9.0",
        "reactabular-table": "^8.9.0",
        "recompose": "^0.23.5",
        "redux": "^3.6.0",
        "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
        "redux-undo": "^1.0.0-beta9-9-1",
        "reflexbox": "^3.0.0-0",
        "schema2object": "^0.4.0",
        "searchtabular": "^1.5.0",
        "segmentize": "^0.4.1",
        "sortabular": "^1.4.0",
        "table-resolver": "^3.1.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
        "react-scripts": "0.9.5",
        "style-loader": "^0.18.2"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      }
    }
```

This line in package.json makes the issue.

#### "react-file-base64": "git+https://github.com/lrojas94/react-file-base64.git"

I am struck with this issue. Kindly help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this exact same error with installing chimp (not from a git repo) after I'd upgraded from NodeJS 6.10 to 8.10 (and more importantly, to NPM 5.6.0).  The problem is that npm 5 handles permissions / directories very differently than npm 4.

The solution is to NEVER use sudo when running npm 5.  You'll find cases of when you have to use it with npm 4, but you shouldn't need to use sudo with npm 5.  If you're installing globally, [this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) might help you.  It didn't help me.

Since I was in a docker container, I could just modify my docker file to not use sudo and then everything was fine.  If you're not, I suggest you run the following as your user (not root):

```
cd ~
sudo rm -rf .npm
cd <wherever your package.json/node_modules is>
npm cache clean
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know whether your problem is solved or not. Today i faced the same issue the problem was ~/.npm folder is messing with permission so I changed permission as `sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm` and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a proper fix (**DON'T DO IT**), but it worked for me. Go to superuser mode and then do `npm install` with `sudo`.

```
sudo su
sudo npm install
```

Comment: Bad practice to give your installed modules a super user privileges, you will eventually have to deal with them with same privileges which is a mess.

Comment: Don't do this or I will reject your prs

Answer (score 0):

The answer worked for me. Recommend using `find` and/or `sudo find` to remove any .npm folder.

Answer (score 0):

Probably nobody is using these Node versions anymore; but if this is your case and no previous answers worked for you; or they don't fit to your case this is the answer.

Use:`runuser -u otheruser -- npm install`

https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/624#issuecomment-1297161342