# sudo npm install gives me a access denied

Tags: node.js, npm, permissions, ionic2

I am using ionic and I have fetched my project through git from machine1 to machine2.

My ionic infos gives me this  :

> [ERROR] Error with ./node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/package.json
>   file: FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> @ionic/app-scripts : not installed
> Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> Node : v8.9.1
> npm  : 5.5.1
> OS   : macOS High Sierra
> ```
>
> Misc:
>
> ```
> backend : pro
> ```

When I run `sudo npm install` I get the following :

> npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to
>   /Users/gerald/Documents/ionic/yesterdayweather/node_modules npm WARN
>   checkPermissions Missing write access to
>   /Users/gerald/Documents/ionic/yesterdayweather/node_modules/@ionic
>
> And then
>
> gyp ERR! configure error gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission
>   denied, mkdir
>   '/Users/gerald/Documents/ionic/yesterdayweather/node_modules/node-sass/build'
>   gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.2.0 gyp ERR! command
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/node/8.9.1/bin/node"
>   "/Users/gerald/Documents/ionic/yesterdayweather/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/nod
>   e-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags="
>   "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library=" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /Users/gerald/Documents/ionic/yesterdayweather/node_modules/node-sass
>   gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok
>   Build failed with error code: 1 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR!
>   errno 1 npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1

I have tried the following solution 1 and 3.

Basically I think I had node installed in a pkg way, so I removed it and intalled it with brew, so actually I should not have this issue.

But I tried anyway option 1 and it still does not work.

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why are you running `npm install` with `sudo`?

Comment: Because when I run it without the sudo I get somewhere : npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Answer (score 17):

It looks like a script is trying to write files, which npm by default denies when running as root. You can put `--unsafe-perm` behind the command to disable this safeguard.

You also should not run npm install with sudo because it is not necessary. <s>Only when using the `-g` flag for installing modules globally should you use sudo.</s>

**2019 EDIT:** It goes without saying that disabling safe guards like this can be very dangerous because you're giving a script a free pass to do whatever it wants. It's best to never use sudo and npm together, even when installing modules globally. If you're running into access issues with npm look into [using a version manager](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm#using-a-node-version-manager-to-install-nodejs-and-npm) or [changing npm's default directory](https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally#manually-change-npms-default-directory).

Comment: Thanks for your help but it did not work, same error

Comment: Oh my god after spending a day on this problem while constantly getting there error  "EACCES: permission denied, mkdir ..." and looking over many stackoverflow posts, this fixed it.

Comment: @SarahMGiles Happy to know that someone found my answer useful!

Comment: This is useful. For sudo, we need it because sometime may cause this error:
`npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `sudo npm install`.  Clean up your environment (see more in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49805455/491553)) and then run just `npm install`.