# Getting Permission Denied with sudo npm install (Bitnami / AWS EC2 / NPM)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, npm, bitnami

I am using the Bitnami Mean Image to try to host my site on AWS EC2. Once I ssh into my EC2 instance and clone my github repo, I try to run sudo npm install but it won't work. My error message is:

> npm ERR! code 1 npm ERR! Command failed: /opt/bitnami/git/bin/git
>   clone --depth=1 -q -b master
>   https://github.com/frozeman/bignumber.js-nolookahead.git
>   /home/bitnami/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4966f918 npm ERR!
>   /home/bitnami/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-4966f918/.git: Permission
>   denied npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/bitnami/.npm/_logs/2018-02-16T07_07_33_645Z-debug.log

Comment: What user are you using? You should log into the server console as the `bitnami` user and run the command as usual. The required environment is automatically loaded for the `bitnami` user.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162403/permission-denied-for-git-clone-when-i-do-npm-install