# permission denied while trying to create leading directories of git clone

Tags: git, npm

Whenever I try to run `npm install` on my app, I get the following error:

```
Eliyas-MacBook-Pro:app-name root# npm install
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk.git /var/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-31357d5e
npm ERR! fatal: could not create leading directories of '/var/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-31357d5e': Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-27T20_18_34_759Z-debug.log
```

This is what I get when I check the permission of the `.npm` folder:

```
drwxrwxrwx   6 root  staff  192 Feb 27 22:11 .npm
```

---

**My environment:**

- git version 2.14.3 (Apple Git-98)
- node v9.4.0
- npm v5.4.0

Comment: Did you try checking the permissions of all of these directories ? (/var/root/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-31357d5e)

Comment: What user installed npm?

Comment: @Omer I couldn't find this folder. Probably because I don't have permission to so. Even tho I'm running with sudo.

Comment: @zee How can I check?

Comment: Try var, then /var/root, then /var/root/.npm/ and so on. What is the last directory you see like this? Which one in this chain is the first that doesn't exist? Try to check the permissions at each step to know which directory has the problematic permissions

Comment: each folder exists. about the permissions, I have no knowledge to know that. I have installed the latest *stable* version of nodejs. It seems to do another error when it stucks on `loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree` which looks like a different kind of error.

Comment: You check the user of a given folder by doing something like this: ls -lad xyz_directory

Comment: I'm running this command as root. I don't see any reason that I should have a problem with read/write folders permissions. I have tried running this command with `sudo` and it got stuck on `loadAllDepsIntoIdealTree` for a couple of minutes, and then it worked. I won't post it as an answer since it's not exactly a solution. It's more of an indirect solution.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45162403/permission-denied-for-git-clone-when-i-do-npm-install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case I recommend you download the master.zip file from the git repo, then install it.

```
$> wget https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk/archive/master.zip

$> unzip master.zip

$> mv master cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk

$> cd (your project dir)

$> cordova plugin add (path to)/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk

$> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="..."  --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="..."
```

---

(update)

The problem might be the git command version is out-of-dated.
In order to upgrade the git command, you may choose :

```
(option 1)
$> brew upgrade git

(option 2)
Install the latest git command from here
https://git-scm.com/
```

Comment: Reasoning? And why it happens?

Comment: I don't know the reason, but definitely your npm or git command problem, such as git command version is old.

Comment: this solution might work, but it solves only a particular dependency. And in case it's about x dependencies, this solution is too complex, therefore I can't accept this answer.

Comment: As I said, it's your environment problem. You should try to update the git command at least.

Comment: Can you add this solution to you answer so I can mark it as the right answer?

Answer (score 2):

I got that error when running `npm install` on a mounted volume on a Jenkins server.

In my case the issue was caused by this bug:
[Failed to install npm package from git in docker since v6.11.0](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/624) 
Which is also mentioned here:
[Cannot install packages from GitHub when mounting directory (node:12-slim)](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/1126)

The bug is fixed in **npm version v6.13.6**

I used node 12.13.0 and upgrading to version >14 (which contains npm version v6.13.6) fixed my problem.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe need root rights.

```
sudo npm install
```